# Calculating Skill Area Range Limit in Game

Tags: python, opencv, math

I am trying to calculate the skill area range in a game.

My script (pasted below) draws ellipse and calculates the skill limit as shown in [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPwZ.png). The skill limit is actually supposed to calculate and draw as shown in the [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArqYa.png). It is neither a full circle nor ellipse in my opinion.

I am missing something to achieve the correct calculation for the skill area range (Image 2), but I can't figure out what. I am out of ideas.

The script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import win32gui


window_name = "Game Window"
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
screen_width = window_rect[2]
screen_height = window_rect[3]

# Range in pixels.
SKILL_RANGE_LIMIT = 380

# Defines the center (the caster is in the center of the screen).
center_x = screen_width / 2
center_y = screen_height / 2

# Defines the color of the circle (in BGR format).
circle_color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green

while True:
    # Gets the current mouse position.
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pyautogui.position()

    # Gets the caster position (it's actually the center of the screen).
    caster_x, caster_y = screen_width // 2, screen_height // 2

    # Calculates the distance between the caster and the target.
    distance = np.sqrt((mouse_x - caster_x) ** 2 + (mouse_y - caster_y) ** 2)

    # Checks if the mouse is within the skill range limit.
    if distance <= SKILL_RANGE_LIMIT:
        print("Inside")

    else:
        print("Outside")

        # Calculates the normalized direction vector from the caster to the max range.
        dx = mouse_x - caster_x
        dy = mouse_y - caster_y
        direction = np.array([dx, dy]) / distance

        # Calculates the new mouse position at the edge of the limit.
        new_x = int(caster_x + direction[0] * SKILL_RANGE_LIMIT)
        new_y = int(caster_y + direction[1] * SKILL_RANGE_LIMIT)

        # Moves the mouse to the new position.
        pyautogui.moveTo(new_x, new_y, _pause=False)

    screenshot = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot(region=window_rect))

    # Draws the skill range limit ellipse.
    img = cv2.ellipse(screenshot, (caster_x, caster_y), (SKILL_RANGE_LIMIT, SKILL_RANGE_LIMIT), 0, 0, 360, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow(window_name, img)

    # Waits for a key press to exit the script.
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

# Cleans up the window.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also, the camera angle can be changed, so I feel like I need to gather some info about the 3rd dimension (`z`) or something else, but I am not sure what and how.

For example, assume the street lamp is the max skill range limit. If I change the camera angle, the script should still calculate correctly.

[image: Image 3],

[image: Image 4],

[image: Image 5]

How can I improve my script to calculate the limit as shown in Image 2, and if possible, the script should support image 3, 4, and 5?

Comment: The line in your second image is clearly a circle, it's just centered off the bottom of the image.  What are we looking at here?  This code clearly did not generate that scene.  Are you hacking another game?  Is it POSSIBLE to get the camera position?  You clearly need that to compute the transform for your skill circle.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I can change the center by increasing `caster_y`. I can play with `caster_y` and `SKILL_RANGE_LIMIT` to have the exact circle that is centered off the bottom of the screen. It is not possible to get the camera position, but the game allows to reset it, so I can somehow have a variable for that.

Comment: I think your wanted area is a circle in 3D space on the ground plane. To draw that in the 2D projection you will need to know the 3D pose of the virtual camera relative to your character. Have a look at OpenGL basics to understand 3D space, camera models and projections. It might be very hard to guess the 3D pose of the cameras from the image. But there is a chance that you could read it from the local game memory space

Comment: Thanks @Micka. I am still a beginner at what I am doing, and what you said sounds like beyond my knowledge. :/